# How to set VirtualBox bios UUID

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to use my native Windows installation in VirtualBox and since it has an OEM license, I need to reuse the bios UUID for the activation to work.

Some system info: 
OS: Arch Linux, kernel 4.1.6-1 
Virtualbox: 5.0.4_OSEr102546

The machine uses raw vmdk disk limited to the 6 partitions that were used by native Windows installation.

I have already applied commands like modifyvm --hardwareuuid and setextradata for a lot of dmi data.

The relevant lines from config are:

```
<ExtraData>
  ...
  <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiBoardLocInChass" value="Type2 - Board Chassis Location"/>
  <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiBoardProduct" value="Lancer 5A5"/>
  <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiBoardSerial" value="string:1052326401165"/>
  <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiBoardVendor" value="LENOVO"/>
  <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiBoardVersion" value="31900058WIN"/>
  <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiChassisSerial" value="YB10465037"/>
  <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiChassisVendor" value="LENOVO"/>
  <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiChassisVersion" value="Lenovo Z50-70"/>
  <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiProcManufacturer" value="Intel(R) Corporation"/>
  <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiProcVersion" value="Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz"/>
  <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemUuid" value="1abbb2fc-c938-11e4-a961-68f728a77e71"/>
  <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/UUID" value="bytes:Gruy/Mk4EeSpYWj3KKd+cQ=="/><!-- UUID in BASE64 -->
</ExtraData>
<Hardware version="2" uuid="{1abbb2fc-c938-11e4-a961-68f728a77e71}">
  <CPU count="1" hotplug="false">
    <HardwareVirtEx enabled="true"/>
    <HardwareVirtExNestedPaging enabled="true"/>
    <HardwareVirtExVPID enabled="true"/>
    <HardwareVirtExUX enabled="true"/>
    <PAE enabled="true"/>
    <LongMode enabled="true"/>
    <HardwareVirtExLargePages enabled="false"/>
    <HardwareVirtForce enabled="false"/>
  </CPU>
  <Memory RAMSize="2560" PageFusion="false"/>
  <Firmware type="EFI"/>
  <HID Pointing="USBTablet" Keyboard="PS2Keyboard"/>
  <HPET enabled="false"/>
  <Chipset type="PIIX3"/>
```

Vboxmanage showvminfo returns this line:

```
Hardware UUID:   1abbb2fc-c938-11e4-a961-68f728a77e71
```

So as you can see, I have used VirtualBox's hardwareuuid setting, dmi setting DmiSystemUuid and UUID (this one I had to reverse engineer from log and find out how to pass it - via base64 and conversion to bytes).

Yet, when I run the machine, VirtualBox somehow decides it knows better and uses the initial UUID of the machine. It's demonstrated in log (last line):

```
00:00:00.586671 ************************* CFGM dump *************************
00:00:00.586674 [/] (level 0)
00:00:00.586680   CSAMEnabled       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:00.586683   CpuExecutionCap   <integer> = 0x0000000000000064 (100)
00:00:00.586686   EnablePAE         <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:00.586687   HMEnabled         <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:00.586689   MemBalloonSize    <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:00.586690   Name              <string>  = "Windows 8" (cb=10)
00:00:00.586692   NumCPUs           <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:00.586693   PATMEnabled       <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:00.586695   PageFusionAllowed <integer> = 0x0000000000000000 (0)
00:00:00.586696   RamHoleSize       <integer> = 0x0000000020000000 (536 870 912, 512 MB)
00:00:00.586699   RamSize           <integer> = 0x00000000a0000000 (2 684 354 560, 2 GB)
00:00:00.586701   RawR0Enabled      <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:00.586702   RawR3Enabled      <integer> = 0x0000000000000001 (1)
00:00:00.586704   TimerMillies      <integer> = 0x000000000000000a (10)
00:00:00.586705   UUID              <bytes>   = "fc b2 bb 1a 38 c9 e4 11 a9 61 68 f7 28 a7 7e 71" (cb=16)
```

Unfortunately, this one is the UUID that matters. In Windows 8 if I use wmic command, it reports UUID: *fcb2bb1a-38c9-e411-a961-68f728a77e71* while I want *1abbb2fc-c938-11e4-a961-68f728a77e71*.

I have deduced that it could possibly be manipulated by extradata starting at root, so I tried to put in line:

```
<ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/UUID" value="bytes:Gruy/Mk4EeSpYWj3KKd+cQ=="/>
```

That changed the log value to the correct one, but wmic still reported the one starting with 'fc'. Also Windows activation didn't work.

So now I'm really out of ideas.

Has anyone been successful in setting this up and if so how?

Comment: The two UUIDs seem to be the same bytes but in different orders. What happens if you swap the order in the value you're supplying?

Comment: Great observation. After reversing the first 4 groups of <ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemUuid"> the wmic returned the correct UUID. Yet activation still didn't work, so I need to search for other Id's that Windows may look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important line is:

```
<ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemUuid" value="1abbb2fc-c938-11e4-a961-68f728a77e71"/>
```

But byte order is reversed in the first four groups, so it needs to be written as:

```
<ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemUuid" value="fcb2bb1a-38c9-e411-a961-68f728a77e71"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you write that in fact what you actually want to DO is to reuse your activation, not merely clone the hardware UUID, the following information might be useful to you (much of it comes from the superlative post https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1071844-start-0.html (incredibly useful reading for anyone trying to virtualize a windows installation) and some of it is what I've seen myself recently):

It is claimed in the above post that in order for Windows activation servers to believe they are being queried by the "same" machine as the physical one, a machine must have the following hardware parameters configured identically with their values in the original machine:

1. the overall machine hardware UUID
2. the serial number of the disk on which Windows is installed
3. the partition UUID of the partition on which Windows is installed
4. if the license is an pre-installed OEM license, of an upgrade from such a license, then the SLIC firmware needs to be installed on the new machine as well.

Notes:
1. The partition UUID is not the same thing as the filesystem UUID for the filesystem on that partition. If you can run linux on the original machine, it's what blkid calls the PARTUUID of the partition.
2. The disk or partition "on which windows is installed" is the one containing the file Windows\System32\winload.exe. It's the partition that MS perversely calls "the Boot partition".  (it's called that because it contains all the System files. The partition that contains the files needed to Boot the machine is called (of course) "the System partition). 
3. I have no idea if/how one imports a SLIC into a virtualbox VM.  The post above explains how to do it if you're using  KVM/libvirt/virsh. 
4. There are definitely VIrtualBox VBoxManage commands to set the hardware UUID, the partition UUIDs of virtual and even raw disks, and the disks serial number. Unfortunately, In VirtualBox (as of the time i write this), the disk serial number can only be set for disks that are attached to a (virtual) SATA or IDE controller.  So VIrtualBox VMs that use virtio or nvme controllers are SOL at the moment. Presumably that will be fixed sometime.

Finally, There is a set of registry keys at HKLM\SYSTEM\HardwareConfig, the values of which seem to be the source of the info that gets displayed by "System Information." By reading the VIrtualBox manual, I succeeded to make the output of System Information be almost identical between the original physical machine and a VirtualBox VM. (I even made a Win 10 VM report System Information as if it was a Win 8 box -- it'd be amusing to see if as a result, entering a Win 8 product key would make the machine think it's activated. The relevant sections of the manual are about "Vendor Product Information" and "Dmi BIOS Information".

I succeeded in getting an activation to work on a machine with a virtual SATA disk, but not on one with a virtual vnme disk -- so i presume that at least (one of) the hard disk and partition UUID are required.